# How to store result of sql query in variable?

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
with cte as
(SELECT top 10 [1],[2]
FROM [tbl_B] where [2] > '2000-01-01' and Status_7 = 0 and         Status_8 = 1 
ORDER BY [2])
,
CTE1 AS
( select [1], row_number() over (order by [2]) as rn
from CTE
)
select [1] from CTE1 where rn = '10'
```

how can I put this into a variable to compare it to another query result?
If i use set @123 = (above query) it gives errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT top 10 [1],[2]
    FROM [tbl_B] 
    where [2] > '2000-01-01' and Status_7 = 0 and Status_8 = 1 
    ORDER BY [2]
)
,CTE1 AS
( 
   select [1], row_number() over (order by [2]) as rn
   from CTE
)
select @123 = [1] from CTE1 where rn = '10'
```

Comment: As a small note, while the `SET @123 = ` will "explode" if there is more than a row, the `SELECT @123 = ` will execute with no problems and put the value of the last row.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
(SELECT top 10 [1],[2]
FROM [tbl_B] where [2] > '2000-01-01' and Status_7 = 0 and         Status_8 = 1 
ORDER BY [2])
,
CTE1 AS
( select [1], row_number() over (order by [2]) as rn
from CTE
)
select @123 = [1] from CTE1 where rn = '10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table variable to store the CTE's result set.  For example:

```
declare @table_var table (id int, col1 varchar(50));

; with  CTE as
        (
        ... your definition here ...
        )
insert  @table_var
        (id, col1)
select  id
,       col1
from    CTE
```

Comparing this with another set can be done with a full outer join:

```
select  coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id
,       coalesce(t1.col1, t2.col1) as col1
,       case
        when t1.id is null then 'Missing in t1'
        when t2.id is null then 'Missing in t2'
        when isnull(t1.col1,'') <> isnull(t2.col1,'') then 'Col1 is different'
        else 'Identical'
        end as Difference
from    @table_var1 t1
full outer join
        @table_var2 t2
on      t1.id = t2.id
```